# Vuex js. passing a selected drop down value between components

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to emit a selected drop down value from one component and use the drop down value on click of refresh button in the parent component basically. Vuex and vuetify are used.

```
component1:
<div>
  <v-btn large class="button-refresh" @click="refreshData()">REFRESH
       </v-btn>
      </div>
js part:
refreshData(){
        if(this.fromTs == '' && this.toTs == '')
        {

            this.fromTs = this.dateRange.fromTs;
            this.toTs = this.dateRange.toTs;
        }

     }
component2 has a dropdown and I need the selected value of it in the refresh data function of component1
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a bit of code around what you're trying to do so people can see how you're currently trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you. I will give you an example about passing data between components.

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Get dropdown value</h1>
    <p>You favorite fast food: {{ food }}</p>
    <SelectDropDown
      label="Select a fast food"
      :options="foods"
      v-model="food"
      autofocus
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SelectDropDown from './SelectDropDown.vue'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      food: '',
      foods: ['Pizza', 'Hamburguer', 'Hot dog']
    }
  },
  components: {
    SelectDropDown
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <select
      class="select"
      :value="value"
      @input="updateValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
    >
      <option
        v-for="option in options"
        :key="option"
        :selected="option === value"
        :value="option"
      >
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    value: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(event) {
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.select {
  margin: 24px;
}
</style>
```

I got this from a VueMastery course: "Next level Vue".

**Child component:**

'inheritAttrs: false': by default, vue pass the attributes from parent to the root child tag (div in this case). By setting inheritAttrs to false, we can use v-bind="$attrs" in the select tag to pass the placeholder to the select tag and not to the div tag. In this example, autofocus is applied to the select tag instead the div tag, so the html attributes pass where we want them.

More info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

***props:***

options: it is set as an array (you can use an object, but it require some extra logic to handle it), the root component send the options by using :options='categories' in this case

label: it is set as an empty string, but we can pass the label using props with :label='Your favorite food' in the root component.

value: the value of the selected option, it is used to send/receive a value to/from the parent, in this case it can be a string or number.

***methods:***

```
updateValue(event) {
    this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
}
```

This method is called on @input event. updateValue receives the event that is happening and emit to the parent an event with the name of input, and pass a payload (event.target.value). In the root parent, v-model is updating when an input event is received, in this case, the payload will set the category data property. If you set a default value for the category property in the root parent, this value will be send to the child as the value prop.

**Parent component:**

You only have to import and use the component. :label will pass a String to the label tag in the child component. autofocus is applied because inheritAttrs is set false.

***Feel free to ask!***

I tried to explain carefully, I'm not a english native speaker so maybe there are some grammar mistakes or I'm not clear enough, and maybe I din't got your point XD, but I hope this can help you.